# Cannot get multiple links to change single rollover to work

Tags: javascript

I can't get multiple links to work I keep getting Uncaught Reference Error:Cannot set property "imgToChange" of null(...) Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
"use strict";
window.onload = rolloverInit;
function rolloverInit() {
    for(var i = 0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
        var linkObj =document.links[i];
        if(linkObj,"id") {
            var linkObj =document.getElementById(linkObj.caption);
            if("imgObj") {
                setupRollover(linkObj,"imgObj");
            }
        }
    }
}
function setupRollover(theLink,theImage) {
    theLink.imgToChange = theImage;
    theLink.onmouseout = function() {
        this.imgToChange.src = this.outImage.src;
    }
    theLink.onmouseover = function () {
        this.imgToChange.src = this.overImage.src;
    }
    theLink.outImage = new Image();
    theLink.outImage = textImage.src;
    theLink.overImage = new Image();
    theLink.overImage.src = "images/" + theLink.id + "Text.gif";
}
 function setupRollover(theLink,australia) {
    theLink.imgToChange = "australiamap";
    theLink.onmouseout = function () {
        this.imgToChange.src = this.outImage.src;
    }
    theLink.onmouseover = function() {
        this.imgToChange.src = this.overImage.src;
    }
    theLink.outImage = new Image();
    theLink.outImage = "images/australiamap.jpg";
    theLink.overImage = new Image();
    theLink.overImage.src = "images/" + caption.id + "adelaide5.jpg";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to pass null to your function, try doing a check before you call it:

```
function rolloverInit() {
    for(var i = 0;i<document.links.length;i++) {
        var linkObj =document.links[i];
        if(linkObj,"id") {
            var linkObj =document.getElementById(linkObj.caption);
            if(linkObj !== null) { //check if linkObj is not null
                setupRollover(linkObj,"imgObj");
            }
        }
    }
}
```